# STR_TO_DATE returns blob value

Tags: mysql

I don't understand why mysql returns a blob value here :

```
SELECT DAT_REAL, STR_TO_DATE(dat_real, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM `entretiens` where dat_real <> ''
```

from phpmyadmin :
[image]

clicking on the blob link leads me to a page saying request =

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dat_real, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM 'entretiens' WHERE 'entretiens'.'DAT_REAL' = '02-09-2010' AND .'STR_TO_DATE(dat_real, '%d-%m-%Y')' = '2010-09-02';`

type of DAT_REAL is varchar(12)

Comment: resolved by activating the mysqli extension in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the data type of "dat_real" field. And also please ensure that it must be a string, since STR_TO_DATE accepts first parameter as a date in string format.